# Removing Ektron widget

Tags: ektron

I believe there is a widget on my page that is causing unbelievably slow page loads. I have narrowed down the exact page it is, and I have about 8 widgets on it. I am trying to disable the widgets one by one, but am having a tough time figuring it out. In the documentation to explains how to remove a widget, but I would like to only temporarily disable them.

These widgets are on PageBuilders, and I have tried to deselect them  in Settings > Configuration > Template Configuration but this does not seem to disable it.

Is there a different way to disable widgets?

I am using Ektron 8.6.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To disable the widget, you could remove the .ascx file from the /widgets folder. The Page should open but report "Cannot load widget" where that widget would appear on the page.

The template configuration setting only prevents you from adding that widget to a new page.

Comment: if I have slow performance due to that widget, would I be able to discover this by removing it?

Comment: Yes. If the widget is causing the delay, the page should display quickly when you disable the troublesome widget.